# Download folder structure from URL

Tags: r

How to download the content of all the subfolders from URL like this?

http://www.pixeltradr.com/dygraphs/

I tried `download.file`, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: you could make a `system` call to [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Answer (score 0):

You may get the source of the page by using a HTTP request and parse your structure by using a HTML/XML/XHTML parser. Looping through the files wouldn't be a problem thus you can download your files by using HTTP requests once you got your structure.

You didn't provide any code so it's very hard to give a detailed answer here.

```
download.file(url, destfile, method, quiet = FALSE, mode = "w",
              cacheOK = TRUE,
              extra = getOption("download.file.extra"))
```

should do the trick. ([Download.File](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/download.file.html))

Comment: OP says they tried ``download.file``. Your answer is just a portion of ``?download.file``...

Answer (score 0):

For this very simple case, the folders are all in links, so this will work

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.pixeltradr.com/dygraphs/"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url,useInternalNodes=T)
href <- doc["//a/@href"]
folders <- data.frame(folder=unlist(href[grepl("/$",href)]))
folders
#      folder
# 1         /
# 2 rgbcolor/
# 3 strftime/
# 4    tests/
```

Note that not all the links are folders, some are just files.

Comment: and how do you use ``download.file``? I tried  ``download.file(folders, some_options)`` without success